# Select only few columns from a table to map with Odata Select query on C# Web API

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp.net-web-api

We have a table in the database which has multiple columns. We only want a query which will return only requested columns. These requested columns will from Odata Select Query requested using C# Web API.
For Example, I have an Employee Table which has below structure in SQL.

[image]

And I am calling below sample API to get the results.
http://domain/controller/method?Select=EmployeeID,EmployeeName

This query should get only above 2 columns from the database; in the current scenario - Database returns all the columns and Odata configurations in Web API filters out the response before returning it to the user
Please help with how to implement this in the database.

Comment: Please include in question OData configuration and your controller method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An example with Entity Framework**

Selection columns "id" and "col3" from the table with columns "id", "col1", "col2", "col3".

```
class filtededMyTableRow
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string col3 { get; set; }
}

// ControllerName/GetCols?colNames=Id&colNames=col3
public void GetCols(string[] colNames)
{
    using (DbEntities context = new DbEntities())
    {
        /*
        MyTable
        id  col1    col2    col3
        1   text1   text2   text3
        2   text1   text2   text3
        3   text1   text2   text3
        4   text1   text2   text3
        5   text1   text2   text3
        6   text1   text2   text3 
        */

        string selArg = string.Join(",", colNames);
        List<filtededMyTableRow> filtededMyTable = context.Database
            .SqlQuery<filtededMyTableRow>($"SELECT {selArg} FROM MyTable")
            .ToList();

        /*
        filtededMyTable
        Id  col3
        1   text3
        2   text3
        3   text3
        4   text3
        5   text3
        6   text3
        */
    }
}
```